# Not authorized using jwt?

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt

I am trying to make a HelloWorld-ish identity server.
I am trying for the service to generate jwt tokens and use them to authenticate users as well as configuring policies to authorize users.

I am already capable to generate tokens, but I keep getting an Unauthorized response when reaching for an endpoint that has the `[Authorize]` attribute.

> DISCLAIMER:
> The following secrets and tokens below are dummy generated. You should never share (or even worst, post in an internet forum, any secrets or jwt or sensitive data). I am doing it because this app won't event reach production. (I am doing it for learning purposes).

Program.cs

```cs
...
// Authorization
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
             Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("26837a75-3199-4e7d-8c31-2c3f53f42e83")),
         ValidateIssuer = false,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ValidateLifetime = false,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
         ValidateActor = false,
         ValidateSignatureLast = false,
         ValidateTokenReplay = false,
         ValidateWithLKG = false
     };
 });

// HTTP request pipeline
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");
app.Run();
```

My token factory (I omit putting the entire controller because this already generates the bearer token):

```cs
    public string CreateToken(
        MetaToken metaToken)
    {
        var tokenDuration = GetTokenDuration(metaToken);
        var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenDuration);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Expires = expiresAt,
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, expiresAt.Ticks.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, metaToken.CreatedAt.Ticks.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, metaToken.Id.ToString())
            })
        };
        return CreateTokenInternal(tokenDescriptor);
    }

    private string CreateTokenInternal(SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor)
    {

        // Setup signing credentials
        var secretBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("26837a75-3199-4e7d-8c31-2c3f53f42e83");
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretBytes);
        var algorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature;
        tokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, algorithm);

        // Create the token
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order your middlewares in the right way, so already the `Authorization` middleware **before** `Authentication` and it couldn't find appropriate claims. make it like this:

```cs
// first validate token and retrieve the claims 
app.UseAuthentication();

// will use the claims that retrieved in the authentication step
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: oh that is embarrassing, that solved it. Thanks!!!